# Open new page without leaving current page

Tags: javascript, ajax

Thanks for reading my question.
I saw Gizmodo & Lifehacker has this feature.
Take a look at this http://lifehacker.com/
When you click link in right sidebar, example (http://lifehacker.com/5835630/apple-launches-itunes-match-beta-for-developers). The address bar show "http://lifehacker.com/5835630/apple-launches-itunes-match-beta-for-developers", it means new page are opened. But contents of current page is not changed, like AJAX load. But the different is: when using AJAX load, we will make request to new page, but address bar is still current URL. And lifehacker.com's address bar shows destination URL, not current URL.
I tried to inspect request, and saw Lifehacker.com make POST request to opened page (http://lifehacker.com/5835630/apple-launches-itunes-match-beta-for-developers), and then render contents, like AJAX load does, but my problem is Why their addres shows new URL instead of URL (or hashbang URL like http://lifehacker.com/#something).
I tested in different browsers, and this feature only work with Chrome & FF, not Opera and IE, so I think is features of Chrome & FF, is it right ?
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved through the HTML5 history API or older hacks that included an iFrame..

See this article on information on HTMl5 History: 
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html

See [this demo](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/examples/history/fer.html) for the [code in question](http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/examples/history/gallery.js).

You may also want to look at the [PJax library](http://pjax.heroku.com/) that provides this functionality (through the above means)

Comment: Thankyou very much, you are my true Hero !

Comment: Btw, does this hack have any disadvantage ?

Comment: Actually it's no hack but a standard. You can easily fallback to the default behavior of changing sites with normal page refreshes.. I'd suggest you check browser compatibility